# Submit form and clear value of text field (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails form to simply post data and using ajax, reload.

`format.js{ render :update do |page|`

`page.reload`

`end}`

I want to also, clear the value of a textbox inside the form because right now, the textboxes just keep the same value. If they were "hello" and the other was "world", I would click submit, it would run `reload`, and keep the same textbox values.

**EDIT** I'm using the default javascripts produced by rails. Prototype.js, application.js (etc.)

Comment: Does this question apply? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284654/rails-resetting-form-fields-with-page-refresh

Comment: If you mean autocomplete is messing my project up, then no. Right now, I simply don't clear the field after I submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting for form like so:

```
page[:the_form].reset
```

You can also update a specific text field value:

```
page[:foo].value = 'Hello!'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an AJAX call, I suspect the right way to clear the form is in your success callback from the ajax call. If you're using ExtJS or jQuery, this should be pretty easy to do, but without letting us know which JS library you use we can't be much more explicit.

Comment: Well, I'm simply using the javascript defaults called by rails. Prototype.